# Program ends after main method

Tags: c#, methods

I'm new to c# and I was trying to make a simple calculator program. However, my program ends immediately after the main method is executed. How do I make the other methods run too?

```
public static void Main(string[]args)
{
    string firstNum; 
    string secondNum;
    string mathOporaters;
}



public static void NumGather(string firstNum, string secondNum, string mathOporaters)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the symbol of the operation you wish to use.");
    mathOporaters = Console.ReadLine();
    if (mathOporaters == "+")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Now enter the fist number you wish to use that oporater on");
        firstNum = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("And now enter the second number");
        secondNum = Console.ReadLine();

        double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(firstNum);
        double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(secondNum);
        char oporater = Convert.ToChar(mathOporaters);
        double answer = (num1 + num2);
    }
    else if (mathOporaters == "*")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Now enter the fist number you wish to use that oporater on");
        firstNum = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("And now enter the second number");
        secondNum = Console.ReadLine();

        double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(firstNum);
        double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(secondNum);
        char oporater = Convert.ToChar(mathOporaters);
        double answer = (num1 * num2);
    }
    else if (mathOporaters == "/")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Now enter the fist number you wish to use that oporater on");
        firstNum = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("And now enter the second number");
        secondNum = Console.ReadLine();
        double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(firstNum);
        double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(secondNum);
        char oporater = Convert.ToChar(mathOporaters);
        double answer = (num1 / num2);
    }
    else if (mathOporaters == "-")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Now enter the fist number you wish to use that oporater on");
        firstNum = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("And now enter the second number");
        secondNum = Console.ReadLine();

        double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(firstNum);
        double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(secondNum);
        char oporater = Convert.ToChar(mathOporaters);
        double answer = (num1 - num2);

        else{
            Console.WriteLine("Im sorry, I don't understand the symbol you entered. Please use one of these: +,  -,  *, /");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it ends cus it finished doing everything you told it to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing very basic fact. I recommend reading [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/).

There you can read:

> The Main method is the entry point of a C# application. (Libraries and services do not require a Main method as an entry point.) When the application is started, the Main method is the first method that is invoked.

When program starts, method are placed on a **stack**. When the stack is empty, **application ends**.

As mentioned, `Main()` mathod is called first and is at the bottom of the stack. So, when it finishes, application ends.

To sum up, it's natural behaviour. If you want to run methods you defined, you need to call them (for example, you could read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)).

Try this:

```
public static void Main(string[]args)
{
    string firstNum; 
    string secondNum;
    string mathOporaters;
    // method call
    NumGather(firstNum, secondNum, mathOporaters);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I try doing that it says that the variables in my parameter are do not exist in the current context. Is it because the variables in the parameter not created in the main method? if so, then how do I fix that?

Comment: You need to assign some value to them, eg. `string firstName = "Patrick";`